# Query a table with limited results, based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's assume I have tbl2, with a foreign key to another table (tbl1). For each record in the tbl1, we can have multiple or no records in tbl2.
I want to have only one record from tbl2 (the last record, based on time), which matches with a record on tbl1. The following query only returns one record:

> select * from tbl2
> where fk in (select id from tbl1 where some_criteria)
> order by time LIMIT 1 DESC

This query also returns all records from tbl2:

> select * from tbl2
> where fk in (select id from tbl1 where some_criteria)
> order by time DESC

I wanna have a row for each record from `select id from tbl1 where some_criteria`, having all details from the latest record exists in tbl2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a lateral join, available since MySQL 8.0.14:

```
select *
from tbl1
left outer join lateral
(
  select *
  from tbl2
  where tbl2.fk = tbl1.id
  order by time desc
  limit 1
) newest_tbl2 on true;
```

Here is a solution for old MySQL versions: Aggregate the tbl2 by fk to get the maximum time per fk. Then use this result in your joins.

```
select *
from tbl1
left outer join
(
  select fk, max(time) as max_time
  from tbl2
  group by fk
) mx on mx.fk = tbl1.id
left outer join tbl2 on tbl2.fk = mx.fk and tbl2.time = mx.max_time;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, is this the only solution? I cannot have it with the normal SQL syntax? I use MySQL 5.7.

Comment: This is a very old version. Must you use that? Can't you upgrade? Another option to get the top n per group is using analytic functions (`ROW_NUMBER`/`RANK`/`DENSE_RANK`). But these require MySQL 8, too. MySQL was rather late to adopt these standard SQL features. We have been calling these "normal SQL" for many years now ;-)

Comment: I have shown one alternative that works in old MySQL versions. There are others. One can outer join tbl2 limited to `where (tbl2.fk, tbl2.time) in (select select fk, max(time) from tbl2 group by fk)` or `where not exists (select null from tbl2 newer where newer.fk = tbl2.fk and newer.time > fk.time)`.